# Why would a select query get in a deadlock?

Tags: .net, sql-server, locking

I am working on a couple of services in .net that use SQL Server 2016. I got a deadlock error a few times today that I'm trying to figure out. The deadlock victim was a stored procedure that does the below query. I thought that using updlock and serializable within a transaction would lock the rows for updates until the transaction is completed, and if a select query ran during the locking, it would still be able to get the committed data. I didn't think a deadlock was even possible with that select query under any circumstances, I mean it's not trying to change the data. Anyone see what I did wrong here?
Error: Transaction (Process ID 337) was deadlocked on resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

```
select  
    pm.DateKey, 
    sum(mm.Numerator) as Numerator,
    sum(mm.Denominator) as Denominator
from fact.MonthlyMeasures mm
join dim.PatientMonth pm on pm.PatientMonthKey = mm.PatientMonthKey   
where 
    mm.MeasureID = @MeasureID and 
    mm.CenterKey = @CenterKey
group by
    pm.DateKey    
order by
    pm.DateKey
```

There is one location each in the .net code where the fact.MonthlyMeasures and dim.PatientMonth table are updated and locking is done. They both follow the same format, so here is the code for one table:

```
public void UpsertPatientMonth(DBPatientMonth patientmonth)
{
    using (var dbConn = _connection.CreateConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            dbConn.BeginTransaction();

            string selectLock = $"select * from dim.PatientMonth with (updlock, serializable) where PatientKey = {patientmonth.PatientKey} and DateKey = {patientmonth.DateKey}";

            var existingPM = dbConn.Query<DBPatientMonth>(selectLock).FirstOrDefault();

            if (existingPM == null)
            {
                patientmonth.insert_date = DateTime.Now;
                dbConn.Insert(patientmonth);
            }
            else
            {
                //removed for brevity
                dbConn.Save(patientmonth);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CustomException("Error updating PatientMonth. Message: " + ex.Message, "upsertPatientMonth");
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConn.CompleteTransaction();
        }        
    }
}
```

I see there is a select * there, not good practice, I realize.

Comment: Select *? It's not great, but it's not _that_ bad. I'm far more worried about using string interpolation rather than query parameters to put values into the sql string

Comment: Can you capture the deadlock event with extended events or Profiler and share with us?

Comment: Extract the deadlock graph and see what is causing it. Deadlocks occur when 2 sessions attempt to obtain the same locks in reverse order, 2 selects can easily do that.

Comment: And even if you don't have READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT set and writers block readers, U lock and S lock are compatible.  So you'll need to share the deadlock XML at least. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It's totally possible to deadlock on select statements. Deadlocks are an issue because locks on tables (and indexes) get taken in different orders. You can prove this to yourself by doing tablockx selects on table A and table B in one SSMS window while trying to do tablockx selects on table B and table A in another window (with appropriate transactions and waitfor statements).

Comment: @GabrieleFranco I do not have permission to do either of these but am requesting it (I have used Profiler before so I will probably start with that)

Comment: I have been unable to replicate this but did get permissions for Profiler, so we will see. But there is another spot in the code where deletions may occur and there's no explicit locking, so I need to investigate that as a possible culprit.